# Remove Vertical Line in Php Storm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

How can i remove this line.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xXXH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the max line length in your code.
Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` and then search for Code Style.
[image: max line length]